# C# Get Object Values

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#.

I have a method that returns an object with the List of objects inside.

```
0   {{DapperRow, RecordedFormID = 'id1'}}   object {Dapper.SqlMapper.DapperRow}

1   {{DapperRow, RecordedFormID = 'id2'}}   object {Dapper.SqlMapper.DapperRow}
```

How can I get those ids as strings?
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeXeO.png)

Comment: Please show your current code, rather than just describing it. Review [mcve].

Comment: In order for us to help you. You will need to provide with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Did you try `.ToString()` ?  Not clear what you've tried, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Linq` namespace and do this:

```
yourObject.Select(x => x.RecordedFormID);
```